# Why is \mathbin{} not the same as a binary math operator in terms of spacing?

Tags: spacing, math-operators

I am trying to redefine a binary math operator, more specifically, I would like to replace `\geq` by `\geqslant`. As far as I understand from a couple of pages on the site, you need to use `\mathbin` for correct spacing. However, in a special case where the text in a line gets too long the spacing still behaves differently.
[image]

What is the difference between the redefined operator with `\mathbin` and the original binary operator? How do you fix this problem?

Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\let\geq\relax
\newcommand\geq{\mathbin{ \geqslant }}

\begin{document}
Normally, the new command works: $a\geq b$ vs. $a\geqslant b$ and $X_{a\geq b}$ vs. $X_{a\geqslant b}$.\\
But $a\geqslant b$ if the text in the line is way too long, it gets all messed up $ABC_{mnopqr}$.\\
But $a{\geq} b$ if the text in the line is way too long, it gets all messed up $ABC_{mnopqr}$.\\
\end{document}
```

Comment: You should use `\mathrel` for relations. But `\renewcommand{\geq}{\geqslant}` is simpler.

Comment: Great! That helped a lot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would need `\mathrel`, because you want a *relation* symbol, whereas `\mathbin` is for symbols like `+` that obey different rules.

However, `\geqslant` is already defined as a relation symbol, so

```
\renewcommand{\geq}{\DOTSB\geqslant}
```

works and is much easier. The `\DOTSB` is for getting the automatic placement of dots right. You can also use

```
\let\geq\geqslant
```

if you feel confident with using low level commands.

Note that in `$a{\geq}b$` the symbol loses its type and becomes an ordinary one (so no spacing around it).

Comment: Maybe note that currently it's usually better to do `\let\geq\geqslant` for math symbols, since doing `\renewcomman\geq{\geqslant}` might alter the automated vertical alignment of `\dots \geq`.